# Mousemove event fires, when it shouldn't

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, mouseleave

I have a problem with `.mouseleave()`.
I want to show a popup when the user leaves the document with his mouse, but the `mouseleave` event keeps firing on entering the document, too.

This **only happens in Chrome**, in Mozzila everything is right.

So this is the code:

```
$(document).mouseleave(function (e) {
    alert('The mouse has left the building!');
});
```

One more thing: the event fires when I scroll, too. I could understand that one, because basically I'm leaving the document, but could I stop that?

Comment: [This](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html) might be your problem

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle that uses the `hover()` method: http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/EmaLB/

Comment: do you have a fiddle?

Comment: In chrome, and you shouldnt use js fiddle for this example, because of the hole iframe stuff.

Comment: Ok, so @JasonSperske thank you the hover idea was a good one, but i had to use it with body, because if i use it with html, or document then the hover runs to, do you understand? And please try this with a simple html file and not js fiddle

Comment: You can access a JSFiddle's iframe directly like this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/sperske/EmaLB/show/

Comment: @JasonSperske ahh ok, didnt new that one, ok so one minute please i will give it a try, until then do you have any idea for the scroll thing ?

Comment: @JasonSperske could you please write your comment as an answer so i can accept it. And thank you

Comment: @AdmiralAdama so what can i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses `jQuery.hover()` ([demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sperske/EmaLB/show/))

```
$(document).hover(function () {
  $('body').css({'background-color': 'red'});
}, function () {
  $('body').css({'background-color': 'green'});
});
```